# SQL merge rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Using Microsoft SQL (Server 12.0.4100.1) I have a simple query like so:

```sql
SELECT OrgLevel3, OrgLevel4, complete, COUNT(*)
FROM #reconcile
GROUP BY OrgLevel3, OrgLevel4, complete
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

The 'complete' column is of type `BIT` so is either 1 or NULL.  So with this query I get two rows for each OrgLevel3/OrgLevel4 pairing.  What I'd rather get is one row with a column of "# Complete" and a second column of "# Incomplete".

Is that possible?

Comment: You could use a union or coalesce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Case` or `IIF` over `SUM`

```
SELECT OrgLevel3, 
 OrgLevel4, 
 sum(iif(complete=1,1,0)) TotalComplete,
 sum(iif(complete IS NULL,1,0)) TotalInComplete,
 COUNT(*)
FROM #reconcile
GROUP BY OrgLevel3, OrgLevel4
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Thanks!  I edited your answer a tiny bit.  Can't check against `complete=0`.  Have to use `complete IS NULL` instead, and then it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. My pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Combine sum and case condition.

```
SELECT OrgLevel3, 
        OrgLevel4, 
Sum(Case when complete is not null 
         then 1 else 0 end) as "# Complete",
Sum(Case when complete is null 
         then 1 else 0 end) as "# Incomplete",
COUNT(*)
FROM #reconcile
GROUP BY OrgLevel3, OrgLevel4
ORDER BY 1, 2, 5;
```